# Script data in one table on one server and insert into the same table in another server 

Tags: sql-server

I have a table on my QA Environment. I want to copy the data from that table to the same table in another environment. How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming you want two table with same data. You can use SSMS Import Data function. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use a tool specifically designed for this - [Red-Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

It costs a little bit - but it's worth every penny ! It will save you loads of grief and time - it can easily compare two existing database tables, and copy only those rows that are new (or have changed). You can work from a SQL backup file, too - excellent stuff. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use an SSIS package.